# Short story about an orc who escapes in a tunnel to warn his kingdom but then gets an arrow through the throat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short fantasy story I read about 22 years ago of an orc, elf or goblin good guy who has news of an impending invasion but gets captured by the enemy and forced to labour underground. He manages to escape through a tunnel and just as he sees the towers of his kingdom he gets an arrow through the throat by his own people. The story ends with the orc/goblin/elf thinking that his people are doomed before he dies.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall where you read this?  Was it an anthology, a magazine or online?

Comment: hey David! yes, it was in an anthology, part of a collection